# how to submit a form without losing values already selected at the same form

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, form-submit

I am using jstl with dropdown lists.

When i click submit button i success the specification but values int dropdownlists are reinitialized.

So I want to submit form without loosing the values already selected in the form because I need to stay always at the same level in the form.To be more clear, user choose a value from ddl and click edit button to show other options and fill them at the same form without loosing what he has selected.

I have tried to deal like that...

```
<form action="myjsp.jsp" method="post">
<input type="Submit" value="Edit">
```

...but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: when trying to integrate your proposition according to my code i found a problem because options are constructed  dynamically from database: so I have like this:
<label> Activity </label>
<select name='activity' id='activity'  onchange='gotoProject()'> 
<option value='-1'>Aucun</option>
<%HtmlListActivityConstruct LA=new HtmlListActivityConstruct();%>
<%=LA.ConstructListActivity("Activity","SELECT from Activityopc activityopc".toString()) %>
</select>
So how could I deal with this situation.

Comment: Could you please explain it more Iam just confused.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preset the inputs with the request parameter values. You can access parameter values in EL by `${param.name}`. Basically:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${param.foo}">
```

Note that this is [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) sensitive. You always need to sanitize the user inputs. You can use the [JSTL functions](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglib for this.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}">
```

In case of dropdowns rendered by HTML `<select>` element, it's a bit trickier. You need to set the `selected` attribute of the HTML `<option>` element in question. You can make use of the ternary operator in EL to print the `selected` attribute whenever the option value matches the request parameter value.

Basic example:

```
<select name="foo">
   <c:forEach items="${options}" var="option">
       <option ${param.foo == option ? 'selected' : ''}>${option}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: I want to understand more this example so to apply it but I did not display my options

Comment: So what we put exactly in each parameter
I am novice
Thank you

Comment: Just substitute "foo" with the actual parameter name. The parameter name is specified in the `name` attribute of the input field.